# Stopping animation (attack) to loop itself when play

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

In unity we know that when animation plays it loops itself (replays) and that is good for movement animation(walk ,run,jump) .

But In my case it is causing a weird effect as shown in pic:

[image: errorloop]

Now when I click and hold the button what I want is that **`the character should take his arm up and then keep it`** unlike taking it again and again till I do not release my finger from button.

Bcoz its an **attack animation** thats why I don't want it !

the attack script and animation call is as follows:

```
public void LaserAttack(){
        isAttacking = true;
        if (robotLeft == true&&isLaserLeft==false) {

            //Debug.Log (firep.position.x);

            //Instantiate (leftLaser, firep.position*1.29f, Quaternion.identity);

            StartCoroutine( DelayMethodLeftInstantiate());

        } 

        if (robotRight == true&&isLaserLeft==false) {

            StartCoroutine(  DelayMethodRightInstantiate());

            //Instantiate (RightLaser, firep.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
        anim.SetBool ("isAttack", isAttacking);
        isLaserLeft = true;

    }

    public void LaserAttackEnd(){
        isAttacking = false;

        anim.SetBool ("isAttack", isAttacking);
        isLaserLeft = false;
}
```

I am calling attack animation in touch button as follows !
[image]

Now how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 3):

Solution is to create a new animation of player **attack still** and using `coroutine`

As we want another animation to be played just after attack animation and when it ends stop both animations (attack) 
to achieve the desired output.

see highlighted one in pic in animator:
[image]

and in code :

```
public void LaserAttack(){
        isAttacking = true;
        StartCoroutine (AttackStillCoroutine ());

        if (robotLeft == true&&isLaserLeft==false) {

            //Debug.Log (firep.position.x);

            //Instantiate (leftLaser, firep.position*1.29f, Quaternion.identity);

            StartCoroutine( DelayMethodLeftInstantiate());

        } 

        if (robotRight == true&&isLaserLeft==false) {

            StartCoroutine(  DelayMethodRightInstantiate());

            //Instantiate (RightLaser, firep.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
        anim.SetBool ("isAttack", isAttacking);
        isLaserLeft = true;

    }

    public void LaserAttackEnd(){
        isAttacking = false;
        attackStill = false;
        anim.SetBool ("isAttackStill",attackStill);
        anim.SetBool ("isAttack", isAttacking);
        isLaserLeft = false;

    }
```

the coroutine is as follows:

```
 IEnumerator AttackStillCoroutine(){

            yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
            attackStill = true;
            anim.SetBool ("isAttackStill",attackStill);

        }
```

Nice and simple...